# POSTing to cross-domain REST service from within an XPage

Tags: xpages

What is the best way to call a cross-domain REST service from within an XPage, I've looked through the Social Enabler app, but in this case I need to also POST a string of content to this service on another server, and then get the response which is JSON and parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Create an xpage which generates json. This is called xagent (  [more info](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn))
2. Create a bean at application scope wich contains code to retrieve data from te service directly using the java url connection and parses the json in a vector or any other java object you can work with
3. Do the same as 2 except constructan instance of the url connection directly in the event code.

For both option 2 and option 3 you could use code like this

```
URL url = new URL(http://yourresthot/restapi);
HttpCOnnection conn = url.openConnection();


if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
  }

  // Buffer the result into a string
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
  rd.close();

  conn.disconnect();
  return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Cross-domain REST service is not possible from the client side Javascript.

There is a workaround for that, using JSONP if the remote service supports this. It basically consists of a script tag referring to another javascript resource on the remote site which is allowed by browsers.

Other than that, if you use a server side REST proxy, you may call the remote service from your XPages. This method is being used for iNotes for instance to integrate with Sametime or Quickr.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lqwiki.nsf/dx/iNotes_proxy_configuration_qd85

This page illustrates how to configure the embedded proxy for your service.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: JSONP
Example: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xsnippets-widget
Code: http://xsnippets.openntf.org

Option 2: Domino/iNotes proxy
http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/DA2F4D351A9F15B28625792D002D1F18/%24file/SocialEnabler111006.pdf section 05.01

Option 3: Your own generic proxy as plugin
http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/DA2F4D351A9F15B28625792D002D1F18/%24file/SocialEnabler111006.pdf section 05.02

Option 4: As described above. Implement server side code to access other servers.

Comment: Thanks - in the end I created a managed bean (which I had never done, but saw how to using http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html) where I did the POST connection, and then in the XPage I used the bean to get data by calling it. I then processed the JSON data in the SSJS button. This works well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java URLConnection to fetch the json data using ssjs and by using "eval" or "toJSON" you can put it in a repeat and display the result with a computed field.